# Submiting multiple forms in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I'm trying modify some php/html code using jQuery to get multiple forms submit at one click.

```
 $html .= "<div class='casephone'>
                                    <h1>".$row['name']."</h1>
                                    <img src='phones/phones/".$phonename."/".$row['imgname_full']."' />
                                    <img src='phones/phones/".$phonename."/".$row['imgname_half']."' /><br />
                                    Wymiary:<br />
                                    Wysokość: <span>".$row['height']."px</span><br />
                                    Szerokość: <span>".$row['width']."px</span>
                                    Rodzaj Canvas: <span>".$row['canvas_name']."</span><br><br><br>
                                    Zmień folder ze zdjęciami etui
                                    <form action='script/editdesccase' method='POST'>
                                                    ".$this->descPhone()."
                                                    <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                                    <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                                </form>
                                    <form action='script/changeheightofcase' method='post' class='wysokosc' target='iframe1'> 
                                        <input type='text' name='height' placeholder='Zmień wysokość telefonu' class='input'/>
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='text' name='idcase' value='".$row['id_canvas']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>
                                    <form action='script/changewidthofcase' method='post' class='szerokosc' target='iframe2'>
                                        <input type='text' name='width' placeholder='Zmień szerokość telefonu' class='input'/>
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='text' name='idcase' value='".$row['id_canvas']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>
                                    Zmień rozmiar Canvas
                                    <h3>Jeżeli wysokość telefony jest większa od 460px to zmień rozmiar Canvas na Wys.: 540px na Szer.: 690px i podmień szablony na większe</h3>
                                    <form action='script/changecanvasproperities' method='POST'>
                                        ".$this->viewSelectCanvasProperities()."
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form' />
                                    </form>
                                    <form action='script/changeimgofcase' method='post' name='zdjecie1' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='iframe3'>
                                        Zmień Szablon telefonu do canvas: <input type='file' name='caseimg'/>
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='text' name='phonename' value='".$_GET['phonename']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>
                                    <form action='script/changeimgofcase1' method='post' name='zdjecie2' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='iframe4'>
                                        Zmień Szablon2 telefonu do canvas: <input type='file' name='caseimg1'/>
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='text' name='phonename' value='".$_GET['phonename']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>

                                    <form action='script/changebackgroundofcase' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='iframe5'>
                                        Zmień Tło telefonu do canvas: <input type='file' name='casebackground'/>
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='text' name='phonename' value='".$_GET['phonename']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>
                                    <h1>Nasze Propozycje - Opcje</h1>
                                    <h3>Wybierz folder z którego będą pobierane nasze propozycje</h3>
                                    ".$this->caseImgPropozition($row['id_dap'], $_GET['phonename'])."
                                    <form  action='script/availablecaseofphone' method='post'>
                                        ".$avaiable."
                                        <input type='text' name='iddap' value='".$row['id_dap']."' hidden />
                                        <input type='submit' value='Zmień' class='submit-form'/>
                                    </form>
                                    <a href='script/removecaseofphone?id=".$row['id_dap']."&name=".$_GET['phonename']."' class='remove-link'>Usuń rodzaj etui</a>
                             </div>
                             <input type='submit' class='koko' value='zaktualizuj'>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.koko').click(function(){
           $('form').each(function(){
           $(this).submit();


           });

        });
    });</script>
";
```

So it looks like jQuery is working here because if I put alert instead of submit I can see pop up few times.
If I put console.log I'm getting `console.log($(this));`

```
    [form#date-form, context: form#date-form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form#option, context: form#option]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form#availablephone, context: form#availablephone]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form.wysokosc, context: form.wysokosc]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form.szerokosc, context: form.szerokosc]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
phone?phonename=vodafonesmartprime6:229 [form, context: form]
```

But no data is changed action redirects me to the homepage. Now I need to do some updates it will involve at least 4 of the forms data to be changed and updated. So I would like to click one button instead of 4 make it quicker.

Comment: Sorry, in my answer you didn't need the whole code again, but just the button part ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Each form has an action, like this: `script/changebackgroundofcase`. I'm not sure what kind of extension should each action target have: `.php`, `.html`, or no extension? So, please fill the actions correspondingly.

But, otherwise, you made `.koko` a submit button. That is not permissible, because it implies the "existence" of an outer form. But there can not be nested forms in document, it's not allowed! So, I just replaced this:

```
<input type='submit' class='koko' value='zaktualizuj'>
```

with this:

```
<input type='button' class='koko' value='zaktualizuj'>
```

Otherwise all seems fine.

If there's still no proper data reading after submits, you'll have to define `id` properties to the controls. Be sure to provide only unique `id` properties for the whole web page.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't need the whole code again, but just the button part ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. The forms are working individually when you click submit of each ones. I've change type submit to button but that didn't fix the problem. Changed data posted via this button not gets update inside the database.

Comment: @nikos83 Have you put in all form actions the extensions `.php`, like this: `script/editdesccase.php`?

Comment: Yes I've changed that but wont work. Also after added extension individual single form return page not found and doesn't work as well.

Comment: Hm, strange forms there :-) Do you mind going in chat to follow some resolving steps?

Comment: I don't mind chat, this is strange app someone created. How can I find you do you use hangouts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146356/discussion-between-aendeerei-and-nikos83).

Comment: @nikos83 Go with ajaxes. Loop through forms, submit each one and place the corresponding results message in an array. After loop display all messages from the array in one place or each of them in a corresponding message div. That's it. The version with one form for all actions is not viable in your case. Good luck!